# Compiling Mongodb 3.6.5 for insertion into Docker image

Tags: c++, mongodb, docker, gcc

## Background

I am trying to compile MongoDB (at the moment the mongos binary, but I think the issue applies to all of the executables) from the code at tag r3.6.5 and use the created binary to replace the binary in the MongoDB docker image.

Running this command:

```
docker run --rm -ti mongo mongos --version
```

returns the following:

```
mongos version v3.6.5
git version: a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: debian81
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

## Issue

One of the compilation checks is:

```
Checking if C compiler is GCC 5.3.0 or newer...no
Checking if C++ compiler is GCC 5.3.0 or newer...no
```

If I use a version of GCC that is greater than 5.1.0 I receive the following message when I attempt to run the container with my executable injected:

```
mongos: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by mongos)
```

According to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) I need to use GCC < 5.1.0 to avoid this, but I also need to use GCC > 5.3.0 in order to compile the branch, so how can I do both?

Comment: Another approach (instead of compiling) would be to copy what the official [`Dockerfile`](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/) does to build the image.

Comment: I am trying to use a modified version of the binary, so compiling is the only option, unless I package my version, and then install that package myself into the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker image needs to contain a C++ runtime that is no older than the one on the system you used to compile mongodb from source. You can sidestep the compiler version check with `--disable-minimum-compiler-version-enforcement` flag, but I can't recommend that: the build system enforces GCC 5.4 for a reason. If your docker image doesn't have the GCC 5.4+ runtime, there isn't much you can do except make a new docker image based on a newer system.